# Rotating an image according to two points

Tags: c#, math, geometry

I have two points on my form, and a picturebox, like this:

```
*

   [^]
   [ ]

          *
```

I would like to align the picturebox with the points, so that it looks like this:

```
*

   \^\
    \ \

          *
```

How would I calculate the angle and how would I rotate the PictureBox?

Currently I'm using this:

```
double xDifference = Math.Abs(point2.X - point1.X);
double yDifference = Math.Abs(point2.Y - point1.Y);

double angle = Math.Atan(yDifference / xDifference) * 180 / Math.PI;
```

But that doesn't work since the x and y values are absolute, and thus they can't calculate it if point 2 is left of point 1.

To rotate the image, I found the following function:

```
    public Bitmap rotateImage(Image image, PointF offset, float angle) {
        // Create a new empty bitmap to hold rotated image
        Bitmap rotatedBmp = new Bitmap(image.Width, image.Height);
        rotatedBmp.SetResolution(image.HorizontalResolution, image.VerticalResolution);

        // Make a graphics object from the empty bitmap
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(rotatedBmp);

        // Put the rotation point in the center of the image
        g.TranslateTransform(offset.X, offset.Y);

        // Rotate the image
        g.RotateTransform(angle);

        // Move the image back
        g.TranslateTransform(-offset.X, -offset.Y);

        // Draw passed in image onto graphics object
        g.DrawImage(image, new PointF(0, 0));

        return rotatedBmp;
    }
```

How would I use that function? I'm not sure what values to insert for offset.

Thanks

Comment: I like the "picture".

Comment: First off, you should not take `abs`, and should use `Math.Atan2`.

Comment: Second, about which point do you want to rotate? If about image's center, your offsets should (`-image.Width/2, -image.Height/2`).

Comment: Third, I doubt that the same size would be enough for rotated image. You seem to need at least `sqrt(2)` times more at each dimension.

Comment: @Vlad, yes I noticed that the image was being cropped (since the rotated image is wider / higher). I'm going to try your suggestions, thanks!

Comment: @Vlad Any advice on calculating the new width and height of the picturebox?

Comment: @Qub1: Well, you can calculate it precisely. `new width = old width * abs(cos(angle)) + old height * abs(sin(angle))`, `new height = old width * abs(sin(angle)) + old height * abs(cos(angle))`

Answer (score 3):

I do not like to use angle when it is not necessary.

Here, you just want to change of orthonormal basis.

From {X;Y} you want to move to {U;V} where V (of norm 1) is parallel to AB (or point1 point2).

Because {U;V} is an orthonormal basis, Ux = Vy and Uy = -Vx.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CsiChart
{
    public partial class CustomControl1 : Control
    {
        private const float EPSILON = 1e-6f;

        private Image _image;
        private ImageLayout _imageLayout = ImageLayout.Center;
        private PointF _pointA = new PointF(0, 100);
        private PointF _pointB = new PointF(100, 0);

        public CustomControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public Image Image
        {
            get { return _image; }
            set
            {
                if (Equals(_image, value)) return;
                _image = value;
                Invalidate();
                OnImageChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }

        public event EventHandler ImageChanged;

        public ImageLayout ImageLayout
        {
            get { return _imageLayout; }
            set
            {
                if (Equals(_imageLayout, value)) return;
                _imageLayout = value;
                Invalidate();
                OnImageLayoutChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }

        public event EventHandler ImageLayoutChanged;

        public PointF PointA
        {
            get { return _pointA; }
            set
            {
                if (Equals(_pointA, value)) return;
                _pointA = value;
                Invalidate();
                OnPointAChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }

        public event EventHandler PointAChanged;

        public PointF PointB
        {
            get { return _pointB; }
            set
            {
                if (Equals(_pointB, value)) return;
                _pointB = value;
                Invalidate();
                OnPointBChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }

        public event EventHandler PointBChanged;

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
        {
            base.OnPaint(pe);
            if (DesignMode) return;

            var g = pe.Graphics;
            g.Clear(BackColor);         

            var image = Image;
            if (image == null) return;

            var clientRectangle = ClientRectangle;
            var centerX = clientRectangle.X + clientRectangle.Width / 2;
            var centerY = clientRectangle.Y + clientRectangle.Height / 2;

            var srcRect = new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), image.Size);

            var pointA = PointA;
            var pointB = PointB;

            // Compute U, AB vector normalized.
            var vx = pointB.X - pointA.X;
            var vy = pointB.Y - pointA.Y;
            var vLength = (float) Math.Sqrt(vx*vx + vy*vy);
            if (vLength < EPSILON)
            {
                vx = 0;
                vy = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                vx /= vLength;
                vy /= vLength;
            }

            var oldTransform = g.Transform;

            // Change basis to U,V
            // We also take into acount the inverted on screen Y.
            g.Transform = new Matrix(-vy, vx, -vx, -vy, centerX, centerY);

            var imageWidth = image.Width;
            var imageHeight = image.Height;

            RectangleF destRect;
            switch (ImageLayout)
            {
                case ImageLayout.None:
                    destRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight);
                    break;
                case ImageLayout.Center:
                    destRect = new Rectangle(-imageWidth/2, -imageHeight/2, imageWidth, imageHeight);
                    break;
                case ImageLayout.Zoom:
                    // XY aligned bounds size of the image.
                    var imageXSize = imageWidth*Math.Abs(vy) + imageHeight*Math.Abs(vx);
                    var imageYSize = imageWidth*Math.Abs(vx) + imageHeight*Math.Abs(vy);

                    // Get best scale to fit.
                    var s = Math.Min(clientRectangle.Width/imageXSize, clientRectangle.Height/imageYSize);
                    destRect = new RectangleF(-imageWidth*s/2, -imageHeight*s/2, imageWidth*s, imageHeight*s);
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }

            g.DrawImage(image, destRect, srcRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            g.Transform = oldTransform;
        }

        protected virtual void OnImageChanged(EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            var handler = ImageChanged;
            if (handler == null) return;
            handler(this, eventArgs);
        }

        protected virtual void OnImageLayoutChanged(EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            var handler = ImageLayoutChanged;
            if (handler == null) return;
            handler(this, eventArgs);
        }

        private void OnPointAChanged(EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            var handler = PointAChanged;
            if (handler == null) return;
            handler(this, eventArgs);
        }

        private void OnPointBChanged(EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            var handler = PointBChanged;
            if (handler == null) return;
            handler(this, eventArgs);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's put all the computations together.

First of all, the direction of the line connecting the two points can be computed by

```
double xDifference = point2.X - point1.X;
double yDifference = point2.Y - point1.Y;

double angleRadians = Math.Atan2(yDifference, xDifference);
```

Then, the vertical direction (90 degrees) must be parallel to the direction considered above after the rotation, so the rotation angle is

```
double rotationAngleRadians = angleDegrees - Math.PI/2;
```

Having this angle, we can compute the bounding box's size:

```
double newWidth =  image.Width * Math.Abs(Math.Cos(rotationAngleRadians)) +
                   image.Height * Math.Abs(Math.Sin(rotationAngleRadians));
double newHeight = image.Width * Math.Abs(Math.Sin(rotationAngleRadians)) +
                   image.Height * Math.Abs(Math.Cos(rotationAngleRadians));
```

Now, we need first to transform in such a way that the middle of the old image is at position 0. This makes translate transform by `(-image.Width/2, -image.Height/2)`. Then, we apply rotation by the `rotationAngleDegrees` (which is `rotationAngleRadians * 180 / Math.PI`), as `Graphics`' rotation expects angle in degrees. Then, we shift the image to be in the middle of the *new* image, that is translate transform by `(newWidth/2, newHeight/2)`.